# make a value selected in drop down when editing

Tags: php, html, smarty

I am adding a feature to edit the ads a user puts. For that I want to make the value selected which is selected by the user when he entered the values . How can I implement this?

```
<div class="nm">
  Category
</div>
<div class="fl">
  <select name="category" id = "ad_category" onchange="cangeSubCat(this.value)" >
    <option value="">---Select Category---</option>
    <option value="real_estate">Real Estate</option>
    <option value="hotels_resturants">Hotels and Resturants</option>
    <option value="car">Car Rental</option> 
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `selected` HTML `<option>` attribute, in XHTML it is `selected="selected"`.

```
<option value="value" selected>title</option>
                      ^^^^^^^^
```

Documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6.1

> I mean how will I know which one should be selected..it will be different for different users . I wnt it to be selected which user selects during adding the ad

That depends on your code. You can do this with an array with all value/title pairs (value => title) and the value which is selected. Then when key (value) equals the selected one, the attribute is added in output. As it's an array it's easy to iterate over it.

```
$otpions = array(
    'a' => 'A',
    'b' => 'B',
);
$selected = 'b';

echo '<select>';
foreach ($options as $value => $title)
{
    printf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>', 
           $value, $selected == $value ? 'selected' : '', $title);
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: in which field I will add this ??

Comment: To the `<option>` that should be selected.

Comment: I mean how will I know which one should be selected..it will be different for different users . I wnt it to be selected which user selects during adding the ad

Answer (score 0):

okay lets assume you fetch value from db and that select box value is in `$select` variable then you've to write

```
  <option <?php if($select=="real_estate") { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value="real_estate">Real Estate</option>
  <option <?php if($select=="hotels_resturants") { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value="hotels_resturants">Hotels and Resturants</option>
  <option <?php if($select=="car") { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value="car">Car Rental</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this magic function

```
function __selectedDb($ctrlValue,$dbValue)
{
    if($ctrlValue == $dbValue)
        return "selected='selected'";
    else
        return "";
}
```

like

```
<select name="category" id = "ad_category" onchange="cangeSubCat(this.value)" >
                        <option value="" <?php echo __selectedDb("","$cat")?>>---Select Category---</option>
                        <option value="real_estate" <?php echo __selectedDb("real_estate","$cat")?>>Real Estate</option>
                         <option value="hotels_resturants" <?php echo __selectedDb("hotels_resturants","$cat")?>>Hotels and Resturants</option>
                         <option value="car" <?php echo __selectedDb("car","$cat")?>>Car Rental</option>    
                    </select>
```

I write in core php please convert php code to smarty